# Swift : You don’t have permission to save the file in the folder “DerivedData”

Tags: xcode, build

Recently, when I create a project on Xcode in swift, the build fails and I get this error message:

Couldn't create workspace arena folder '/.../Xcode/DerivedData/program': You don’t have permission to save the file “program” in the folder “DerivedData”.

How to solve it ?

Answer (score -1):

Xcode>Preferences>Accounts>Menage Sertificates> + > Done
Couple time refresh Xcode

and before press Run app don't press to Resume on preview